# Terraform Create Azure IoT Device Provisioning Service Enrollment Group

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-resource-manager, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I've been trying to create an Azure IoT Hub Device Provisioning Servince along with Enrollment Group that is using X509 Certificates.

As far as I can see there's no way to do it using `azurerm` provider. I've also tried to explore `azapi` options but it seems like `type = "Microsoft.Devices/provisioningServices@2022-12-12"` also won't be able to offer automatic enrollment group creation?

Is there any other provider I could use for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I ended up using `local_file` to create a temporary cert file and then `null_resource` to run Azure CLI commands, my solution:

```
locals {
  iot_hub_name = join("-", [var.project_name, "iothub", var.environment_name])
  dps_name     = join("-", [var.project_name, "dps", var.environment_name])
  cert_path    = "intermediate"
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_iothub" "azure_iot_hub" {
...
}

resource "azurerm_iothub_dps" "azure_iot_hub_dps" {
...
}

resource "local_file" "create_cert_file" {
  content  = var.iot_dps_intermediate_cert
  filename = local.cert_path
}


resource "null_resource" "create-dps-certificate-enrollement" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    command     = <<-EOT
      az login --service-principal -u $CLIENT_ID -p $CLIENT_SECRET --tenant $TENANT_ID
      az extension add --name azure-iot
      az iot dps enrollment-group create --cp $CERT_PATH -g $RESOURCE_GROUP --dps-name $DPS_NAME --enrollment-id $ENROLLMENT_ID 
    EOT
    environment = {
      CLIENT_ID      = data.azurerm_client_config.current.client_id
      TENANT_ID      = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
      CLIENT_SECRET  = var.client_secret
      RESOURCE_GROUP = var.resource_group_name
      DPS_NAME       = local.dps_name
      ENROLLMENT_ID  = "${local.dps_name}-enrollement-group"
      CERT_PATH      = local.cert_path
    }
  }

  depends_on = [local_file.create_cert_file]
}
```

where `var.iot_dps_intermediate_cert` represents the content of `.pem` file that is used to create a new Enrollment Group